# allocating ivar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management

why I can't simple:

```
self.list = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"Who Hash", @"Bubba Gump Shrimp Étouffée", @"Who Pudding", @"Scooby Snacks", @"Everlasting Gobstopper", @"Green Eggs and Ham", @"Soylent Green", @"Hard Tack", @"Lembas Bread", @"Roast Beast", @"Blancmange", nil];
```

instead of:

```
NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Who Hash", @"Bubba Gump Shrimp Étouffée", @"Who Pudding", @"Scooby Snacks", @"Everlasting Gobstopper", @"Green Eggs and Ham", @"Soylent Green", @"Hard Tack", @"Lembas Bread", @"Roast Beast", @"Blancmange", nil];
self.list = array;
```

Comment: You can, why do you think you can't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both methods you have posted are leaking.

Assuming that `list` is declared as a property like this...

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *list;
```

Then we know that when setting list via the synthesized setter, using `self.list = xxx`, that it will be retained and have a retain count of 1. Additionally by calling alloc/init, the retain bumps up again to 2. Having said that, we could rewrite your two approaches in a memory safe way, like this...

```
self.list = [[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"A", @"B", @"C", nil] autorelease];
```

or

`self.list = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"A", @"B", @"C", nil];`

or

```
NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"A", @"B", @"C", nil];
self.list = array;
[array release];
```

Comment: just a nitpick -- the retain count would be 1 because of the alloc/init and 2 because of the property retain.  you said it backward.

Comment: I realize that. I was just going along as if you're reading from left to right.

Answer (score 4):

Actually you can. But if list property is declared as retain you have to do it like this:

```
self.list = [[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"Who Hash", @"Bubba Gump Shrimp Étouffée", @"Who Pudding", @"Scooby Snacks", @"Everlasting Gobstopper", @"Green Eggs and Ham", @"Soylent Green", @"Hard Tack", @"Lembas Bread", @"Roast Beast", @"Blancmange", nil] autorelease];
```

OR even shorter:

```
self.list =  [NSArray arrayWithObjects: "Who Hash", @"Bubba Gump Shrimp Étouffée", @"Who Pudding", @"Scooby Snacks", @"Everlasting Gobstopper", @"Green Eggs and Ham", @"Soylent Green", @"Hard Tack", @"Lembas Bread", @"Roast Beast", @"Blancmange", nil];
```

Otherwise you'll get the leak.